# Foreground service in API Level 24 - Android 7.0 Nougat

Tags: android, service, android-api-levels

My question is specific to API LEVEL 24 - Android 7.0 Nougat.
I am trying to find the most appropriate and futureproof way to start a sticky foreground service. 
To sum up:
- The service needs to be started from an activity after a button press
- A (sticky - this will be handled by notification flags) notification will be created

In API level 26, we can call `startForegroundService(service, notification)` and the service is automatically corellated to the notification.
However in API level 24, the service is started with `startService(service)` and the notification is displayed by calling NotificationManagerCompat's `notify` method.
How can we let the OS know that the notification is related to the service, so the service is considered a foreground service, that the OS will never kill by itself.

Note: the reason I want this implementation is to be futureproof. This service needs location updates and starting from API Level 26, only foreground services (with sticky notification) are able to receive real time updates (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can we let the OS know that the notification is related to the service, so the service is considered a foreground service

Call `startForeground()` in the service, supplying the `Notification`. You need to do this on Android 8.0+ as well.

> that the OS will never kill by itself

That has never been the case. It simply makes it less likely that Android will terminate your process.

Comment: StartForeground is not available on api level 24 though. That's my problem

Comment: @AlexandrosD: `startForeground()` has been around since API Level 5: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startforeground

Comment: Oh I see - `startForeground` is a service method, and all the notification related code needs to managed by the service - sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Is anyone aware of a method to implement a service that will NEVER get terminated by Android?

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle: Build your own custom ROM and implement your logic as a standard Linux daemon.